# sequelize association N:M Table and 1:N Table

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize, mysql for node.js! 
Have a question and post it.
First, to create a review table with N: M relationship between user table and store table!
Please refer to the ReviewImage Table, which is a 1: N relationship with the Review Table.
 For synchronization, please refer to the Review Table and ReviewImage Table.
I don't know what the problem is even if I browse the sequelize API documentation!
Have you ever done the wrong database design?
Should I design a review image table?

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require('../config/config')[env];
const db = {};

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  config.database, config.username, config.password, config);

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.User = require('./UserModel')(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.Store = require('./StoreModel')(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.Review = require('./reviewModel')(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.ImageReview = require('./imageReviewModel')(sequelize, Sequelize);

/** N:M User : Store (Review) */
db.User.belongsToMany(db.Store, { through: db.Review});
db.Store.belongsToMany(db.User, { through: db.Review});

/** 1:N review : imageReview */
db.Review.hasMany(db.ImageReview);
db.ImageReview.belongsTo(db.Review);

module.exports = db;
```

```
// userModel.js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    return sequelize.define('User',{
        userPlatformType:{
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        },
        userNickname:{
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
            allowNull: false,
            unique : true,
        },
        customerEmail: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true,
        },
        userPassword:{
            type: DataTypes.STRING(200),
            allowNull: false,
        },
        salt:{
            type: DataTypes.STRING(200),
        },
        userPhoneNumber:{
            type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
        },
        userDateOfBirth:{
            type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
        },
        userWeddingDay:{
            type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
        },
        userProfile: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(200),
            allowNull: true,
        },
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true,
    });
};
```

```
// storeModel.js

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    return sequelize.define('Store',{
        storeName:{
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        },
        storeCategory: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true,
        },
        storeAddress:{
            type: DataTypes.STRING(150),
            allowNull: false,
            unique : true,
        },
        storeLatitude:{
            type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
        },
        storeLongtitude:{
            type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
        },
        storeCondition: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(200),
            allowNull: false,
        },
        storePhoneNumber:{
            type: DataTypes.STRING(200),
            allowNull: false,
        },
        storeProfile:{
            type: DataTypes.STRING(200),
        },
        storeWifi:{
            type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
        },
        storePost:{
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
        },
        storeItem:{
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
        },
        storeIntro:{
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
        },
        storeLike: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            defaultValue: 0,
        },
        storeRating: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            defaultValue: 0,
        },
        storeIsJoin: {
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            defaultValue: false,
        },
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true,
    });
};
```

```
//ReviewModel.js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    return sequelize.define('Review',{
        reviewWriter :{
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
            allowNull: false,
        },
        reviewContent :{
            type: DataTypes.STRING(200),
            allowNull: false,
        },
        reviewGrade : {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        reviewIsDeclare : {
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            allowNull: false,
        },
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true,
    });
};
```

```
//ReviewImage.js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    return sequelize.define('ImageReview',{
        reviewImageUrl :{
            type: DataTypes.STRING(200),
            allowNull: false,
        },
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true,
    });
};
```

Comment: Please show model definitions

Comment: i need your help..

Comment: What exact problem do you have with models? Their definitions and associations looks good though I would recommend to add primary key definitions explicitly